# Using Images of high resolution gives an BITMAP error?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have created an application which consists of only ImageViews.

Also According to the app requirement I had to use Hi Quality Images with 1024*780 Resolution through 200*250 resolution Images. All Images sums up to almost 45 images!!!.

In High-End (Heap memory >=32)Devices, I found it is running Smoothly, Coming to the low end (Heap memory <32) devices & also on MICROMAX A 65, I received Some Crashing Reports & I gave a try on a 16mb heap memory Emulator.

After Clicking first Image it is showing:

```
06-29 05:16:28.572: W/dalvikvm(846): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40a70930)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:616)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:349)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.mshah.learnandplaybasiccolors.Learn.setImageWithSound(Learn.java:123)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.mshah.learnandplaybasiccolors.Learn.onClick(Learn.java:88)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-29 05:16:28.665: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not using Bitmap, It is giving the bitmap error: How can I resolve this error ???

or

Should I exclude the support for such devices?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't load all these images into memory at the same time.  Why would you? You should create some gallery of thumbnails or something along those lines and lazy load as needed.  There is no way around this.  You're going to run out of memory loading images the way you're doing, even on the high end devices since android only gives you a very small memory footprint within which to operate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.,Your point is right, But I am using the iMages continuously on Click of button I'l show them in full screen (Here comes the Images with Higher res.), So that I maintained some time for the "gc" to recycle the memory. For low heap memory only it is showing the "Out of memory" error and closing the app.??

Answer (score 0):

[Managing bitmap memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

this doc is helping a lot regarding bitmap issue.